# interpolate(method="nearest") in a groupby in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset that I want to groupby("CustomerID") and fill NaNs with the nearest number within the group.

I can fill by nearest number irregardless of group like this: 
`df['num'] = df['num'].interpolate(method="nearest")`

When I tried: 
`df['num'] = df.groupby('CustomerID')['num'].transform(lambda x: x.interpolate(method="nearest"))`

I got ValueError: x and y arrays must have at least 2 entries, which I assume is because
some customers only have one entry with NaN or only NaNs.
However, when I extracted a select few rows that should have worked and made a new dataframe, nothing happened.

Is there a way I can group by customerID and fill NaNs with nearest number within the group, and skip customers with only NaNs or just one observation?

Comment: can you provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? (sample data and expected output)

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same "ValueError: x and y arrays must have at least 2 entries" in my code. Adapted to your code (which I obviously could not reproduce) here is how I solved the problem:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df.loc[:,'num'] = df.groupby('CustomerID')['num'].apply(lambda group: group.interpolate(method='nearest') if np.count_nonzero(np.isnan(group)) < (len(group) - 1) else group)

df.loc[:,'num'] = df.groupby('CustomerID').apply(lambda group: group.interpolate(method='linear', limit_area='outside', limit_direction='both'))
```

It does the following:

1. The first "groupby + apply" interpolates each group with the method 'nearest' ONLY if the group has at least two non NaNs values.

`np.isnan(group)` returns an array containing True where group has NaNs and False where it has values.

`np.count_nonzero(np.isnan(group))` returns the number of True in the previous array (i.e. the number of NaNs in the group).

If the number of NaNs is strictly smaller than the length of the group minus 1 (i.e. there are at least two non NaNs in the group), the group is interpolated using 'nearest', otherwise it is left untouched.

2. The second "groupby + apply" finishes to interpolate each group, using method='linear' and argument limit_direction='both'.

- If a group was fully interpolated in the previous step: nothing
  happens.
- If a group had only one non NaN value (therefore was left
  untouched in the previous step): The non NaN value will be used to
  fill the entire group.
- If a group had only NaNs (therefore was left untouched in the previous step): the group remains full of NaNs.

Here's a dummy example using your notations:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'CustomerID':['a']*3+['b']*3+['c']*3,'num':[1,np.nan,2,np.nan,1,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan]})
df
  CustomerID  num
0          a  1.0
1          a  NaN
2          a  2.0
3          b  NaN
4          b  1.0
5          b  NaN
6          c  NaN
7          c  NaN
8          c  NaN

df.loc[:,'num'] = df.groupby('CustomerID')['num'].apply(lambda group: group.interpolate(method='nearest') if np.count_nonzero(np.isnan(group)) < (len(group) - 1) else group)
df
  CustomerID  num
0          a  1.0
1          a  1.0
2          a  2.0
3          b  NaN
4          b  1.0
5          b  NaN
6          c  NaN
7          c  NaN
8          c  NaN

df.loc[:,'num'] = df.groupby('CustomerID').apply(lambda group: group.interpolate(method='linear', limit_area='outside', limit_direction='both'))
df
  CustomerID  num
0          a  1.0
1          a  1.0
2          a  2.0
3          b  1.0
4          b  1.0
5          b  1.0
6          c  NaN
7          c  NaN
8          c  NaN
```

**EDIT: important note**

The interpolate method 'nearest' uses the numerical values of the index (see documentation https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.interpolate.html). It works well in my dummy example above because the index is clean. If the index of your dataframe is messy (e.g. after concatenating dataframes) you may want to do `df.reset_index(inplace=True)` before you interpolate.

Comment: I don't think `limit_area='outside'` is needed in this case since you only have one value to extrapolate both sides. Also, note that pandas groupby got an update and now you need to specify the `group_keys` argument. In both steps you want to add: `df.groupby(['CustomerID'], group_keys=False)`